# Maximize the expression on two arrays

Tags: algorithm

I have the following algorithmic problem.

You have two arrays ``A and `B` of the same length and values are positive integers. For example:

```
A = [6, 3, 4, 8, 3]
B = [2, 4, 2, 1, 2]`
```

You need to find such two indexes `i, j` where `i != j` such that expression `A[i] * B[i] + A[i] * B[j] + A[j] * B[j]` is maximized. For example here it is `i = 3, j = 1` which gives maximum of `52`

$O(n^2)$ solution is obvious (just two loop) but I am not sure if there exist a better algorithm. I also tried to do sorting based on `A/B` or `A*B`, but none of them gave me any better solution

Answer (score 0):

Use convex hull trick for `nlogn` solution.
[convex hull trick tutorial](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63823)